# How to merge two of the same excel sheet with different data

Tags: excel

I want to be able to do this without the use of copy and paste, because there's way too many data on each, and would take hours or even days to finish. Here's an example of what I want to happen.

```
|  Name  |   Street   | Number |
   John      Blue RD     147
             Red RD

  George    Yellow RD    543
```

PLUS

```
|  Name  |   Street   | Number |
             Blue RD     
   Paul      Red RD       352
   Ringo                  368
```

EQUALS

```
|  Name  |   Street   | Number |
   John      Blue RD      147
   Paul      Red RD       352
   Ringo                  368
   George    Yellow RD    543
```

- And blank spaces are suppose to happen, thanks to anyone who has a solution to this, I've searched everywhere and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a 3rd sheet in which each cell will be a function of the two.

For example, the `A1` cell will contain:

```
=IF(ISNA(Sheet1!A1),Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1)
```